# Qt C++ default parameter for widgets?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a question concerning default parameters:

In a method, I can use default parameters for an int like for `index` in the following code, to allow execution without a value for `index`:

```
void readFromXML(const XMLDocumentWrapper *const doc, const int index = 0);
```

Now I have several sets of `QLabel`. I want to enable/disable these sets of `QLabel`. But the amount of `QLabel` is not the same in every set. Some sets have 4 `QLabel`, while some have only 2 or 3.

I thought of writing just 1 method and using default parameters. I don`t want to overload my method because there are too many possibilities with 4 parameters to enable/disable.

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
void en_disable(bool bl , QLabel * const lab1,..., QLabel * const lab = 0 )     ???
void en_disable(bool bl , QLabel * const lab1,..., QLabel * const lab = NULL )  ???
```

**Can I use default parameters for widgets as well like for example integers to allow execution without a value for my *QWidget lab*** ?

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Also post some details about the content of `en_disable` and where/how it is used: that could help to propose the best solution to your problem. By the way, I am curious to know why `readFromXML` takes a pointer as first argument

Comment: The answer is _yes, you can_. It looks like `void f(QLabel *label = NULL)` (you also can write `0` or `nullptr`, here is no difference). A tip is _try to pass a list of labels to disable:_ `void en_disable(bool bl, QList<QLabel *> &labels)`.